# ffmpeg not being able to convert bluray_pcm audio to normal PCM audio in M2TS files?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a test scenario where I have a M2TS file (called `1.m2ts`) that contains one video track and several audio tracks. One of the audio tracks is unusual in that it is in `bluray_pcm` format.

In the first step, I would like to create a new M2TS file (called `2.m2ts`) from `1.m2ts` that has all audio tracks except the `bluray_pcm` track removed.

In the second step, I would like to convert `2.m2ts` into MKV format (file `3.mkv`).

Because MKV seems to be unable to cope with a `bluray_pcm` track, I also convert the `bluray_pcm` track to normal PCM audio during the first step.

The first step works in principle, but ffmpeg makes a mess out of the codec tags. After having noticed it, I have researched the subject and found that I should add `-map_metadata` to the command line, but unfortunately, that didn't help. The following shows the command lines and the changes in the codec tags:

First, I have let ffprobe output the track data from the original file, `1.m2ts`:

```
ffprobe -print_format json -loglevel fatal -show_streams -count_frames -i 1.m2ts > 1.json
```

`1.json` then had the following content (leaving away irrelevant lines):

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mpeg2video",
            "codec_long_name": "MPEG-2 video",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "HDMV",
            "codec_tag": "0x564d4448",
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "ac3",
            "codec_long_name": "ATSC A/52A (AC-3)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "AC-3",
            "codec_tag": "0x332d4341",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "codec_name": "ac3",
            "codec_long_name": "ATSC A/52A (AC-3)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "AC-3",
            "codec_tag": "0x332d4341",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "codec_name": "pcm_bluray",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 16|20|24-bit big-endian for Blu-ray media",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "HDMV",
            "codec_tag": "0x564d4448",
            "sample_fmt": "s16",
        },
    ]
}
```

So far, so good. As we can see, the `bluray_pcm` track is track 3.

Then I created `2.m2ts` as described above:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100G -probesize 100G -fix_sub_duration -copyts -i 1.m2ts -map 0:0 -map 0:3 -map_metadata 0 -muxpreload 0 -muxdelay 0 -vcodec copy -acodec pcm_s16le 2.m2ts
```

Note that the command line contains `-map_metadata 0`.

The command went through without errors, so it was time to analyze `2.m2ts` using the method shown above:

```
ffprobe -print_format json -loglevel fatal -show_streams -count_frames -i 2.m2ts > 2.json
```

`2.json` then contained (again, leaving away irrelevant parts):

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mpeg2video",
            "codec_long_name": "MPEG-2 video",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "[2][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0002",
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "bin_data",
            "codec_long_name": "binary data",
            "codec_type": "data",
            "codec_tag_string": "[6][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0006",
        }
    ]
}
```

So the audio codec now is "bin_data". And furthermore, the `codec_tag_string` and the `codec_tag` for the video track are messed up as well.

Consequently, when trying to convert `2.m2ts` to `3.mkv`, the following happens (again, irrelevant lines left away):

```
ffmpeg.exe" -i 2.m2ts -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -codec copy 3.mkv

Input #0, mpegts, from '2.m2ts':
  Duration: 01:46:24.34, start: 11.650667, bitrate: 22115 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 30000000/0/0 buffer size: 9781248 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
File '3.mkv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
[matroska @ 000001f6cfd4d340] Tag [6][0][0][0] incompatible with output codec id '98314' ([0][0][0][0])
[out#0/matroska @ 000001f6cfd25dc0] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening output file 3.mkv.
Error opening output files: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Now I'd would like to know where my mistake is. The procedure that I use in step 1 (remove all audio tracks except the `bluray_pcm track` and convert that track to normal PCM) is described in multiple tutorials and questions & answers, respectively.

Why it messes up the video track metadata is also beyond my horizon (although this doesn't have have negative side effects, apparently).

What exactly do I need to do to convert a `bluray_pcm` track in a M2TS file to normal PCM so that the resulting M2TS file can be processed further afterwards, and how do I prevent ffmpeg from altering the codec tags?

Comment: It looks like `m2ts` container doesn't support `pcm_s16le` codec. Executing `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -t 10 test.m2ts` there is a warning message: `Stream 0, codec pcm_s16le, is muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading`.  According to the [following post](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/394427-Muxing-wav-mpeg2-to-ts-using-ffmpeg-losing-audio), "normal pcm isn't allowed in transport stream and ffmpeg has no option to convert to lpcm". Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10051250/4926757).

Comment: In case the PCM is just stored as "intermediate codec", you may use AVI container: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -t 10 test.avi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rotem pointed out in comment, LPCM isn't directly supported in MPEG-TS. However, you can package it as a SMPTE ST 302 stream using `-acodec s302m -strict -2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, accepted and +1. Then it was my own mistake ...